# Converting JSON to Java / Scala using GSON (or any other Library) -> Bean Structure unclear

Tags: java, json, scala, gson

I have got this JSON string:

```
    {
  "totalSize" : 2,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Article__c",
      "url" : "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Article__c/a01d00000030gSxAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "ABC - Fri Mar 30 01:54:57 CEST 2012"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Article__c",
      "url" : "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Article__c/a01d00000030gSaAAI"
    },
    "Name" : "XYZ - Fri Mar 30 01:52:25 CEST 2012"
  } ]
}
```

I need a Java object to get values of keys. I tried to use Gson (but another easy solution would also be ok). I thought the structure of the beans should be this:

```
case class AttributeBean(typ: String, url: String)
case class RecordBean(attributes: List[AttributeBean], name: String)
case class ResponseBean(totalSize: Int, done: Boolean, records: List[RecordBean])
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I do the following Gson call:

```
val response : ResponseBean = gson.fromJson(responseAsString, classOf[ResponseBean])
```

There is no exception, but I get this WRONG content of the bean:

```
ResponseBean(0,false,null)
```

It should be 2, true, "list with records". Can someone tell me the correct structure of the beans to parse the JSON string?

Thank you in advance...

Best regards, 
Kai

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand the notation you use. However I see several bugs there:

- Attributes is not a list, just an object, or at least that is what your json states
- `AttributeBean`'s field should be `type`, not `typ`
- `Name` attribute should be cap-cased in the class definition (if I look at the json)

Otherwise your expectations of GSON seem fine and the code too. GSONis easy to use and I seriously recommend it. The only other problems that can occur in your code are scala-ralated, because I do not understand the language.

**EDIT** Adding a Java example of how to have a class field not matching the json field:

```
{
   "type" : "Article__c",
   "url" : "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Article__c/a01d00000030gSxAAI"
}
```

And the java code:

```
public class AttributeBean {
    public String url;
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String typ;
}
```

Because of this annotation the parsing will go ok.

Comment: It's scala, and type is a keyword in scala.

Comment: I'm not the asker, in case you were asking me.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I fixed the "Name" and "attributes: List" bugs. Though, I cannot change "typ" to "type" because it is a keyword in Scala. I need a workaround here. Maybe the Gson user guide will help me. At the moment, my bean.toString is still: "ResponseBean(0,false,null)". Because there is only the "typ" bug, shouldn't it be "ResponseBean(2,true,null)" already?

Comment: To use keywords as identifiers, surround them with backticks: so `\`type\`` refers to the identifier `type`.

Comment: If it was java I could have helped you. Can I include my Java fix of the serialzed name not matching the class field?

Comment: Thanks for the backticks hint... Though, it still does not work. Maybe it is a Scala issue. I will try Java first, it reduces number of potential problems. @Boris: I would appreciate if you post your Java solution...

Comment: @KaiWähner - I already added some java code, have you seen? Write back if you need some more, but most of it is quite similar to the one you provided.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Oh, I didn't see that... Now I created Java classes only. I can't even get a very simple example working. Even other Hello World examples do not run. I get this exception. It seems that some kind of reflection is happening and not working? Libraries should be ok, I added them via Maven. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.isArray(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Z
 at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:111)
 at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContextDefault.serialize(JsonSerializationContextDefault.java

Comment: Maybe problem with the GSON version? Never seen that kind of error.

Comment: Strange. The error occurs with different, independent files / examples. I use the current version (2.1) via Maven. Damn, I just tried to get a quick solution for reading a single JSON file... Maybe I have to try another library, now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9504/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-kai-wahner)

Comment: Finally, I got it working with Java Beans. Scala case classes do not work for me, but Java Beans are fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Gson does not natively work with Scala "case classes". Your two best options for using Json with "case classes" are [Jerkson](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson) and [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/). After working with both, I'd recommend Jerkson for its speed and support of streaming reads and writes, but both libraries should satisfy your use case.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I will try out one of these tomorrow... I think case classes are a very good use case for JSON parsing - much less boilerplate code...

Comment: I agree! Much less boilerplate, and you can add methods to the case classes to help transform the parsed data.

Comment: Jerkson doesn't have Scala 2.10 support. I've found an alternative fork of Jerkson project that has 2.10 support implement, but it hasn't  a maven repository to retrieve the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can name your field `` `type` `` (in backticks), that might help getting around the issue of field names being already taken by keywords.